# Nested push animations iOS7 bug?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uistoryboardsegue

I just encountered a problem with an app I bug-tested. I was banging my head to the wall to understand why I got this error:

```
2013-11-25 09:02:55.687[186:60b] nested push animation can result in corrupted   navigation bar
2013-11-25 09:02:56.055[186:60b] Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted.
2013-11-25 09:02:57.666[186:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't add self as subview'
```

After a while i created a new project to try to reproduce the bug:

This happends when I press down on two bar button items with different segues, and then release at the same time. I'm using story boards with segues and have NO self written code whatsoever. Is this an iOS7 bug, or am I missing something?

I have not been able to reproduce on simulator, since I don't have two cursors... I am using an iPad2 with iOS7 7.0.3

Image of story board:

[image]

EDIT:

Since I got smashed and totally downvoted without noone even trying to reproduce and confirm this bug, I've reported it without confirmation.

EDIT2:

Apple asked for a Stack trace. But since I gave them the exact steps to reproduce, I didn't bother. It's not my job. So feel free to report this.

Comment: how it will generate the bugs if you try to click any button

Comment: I press both bar button items, hold down on them. and release at the same time.

Comment: This is not a programming question and should really be on the Apple boards or in a radar if you believe it is a bug.

Comment: I am sorry if it is in a wrong place. I'm not sure if it's a bug but it sure looks like it. I placed it here to get some feedback and perhaps see if anyone else can reproduce it.

Comment: A temporary work-around could be to disable the other button on press gesture.

Comment: As Fogmeister noted, if you have found a reproducible bug, please log it at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: your image and questions are not be similar. where is navigation bar button?

Comment: @iDev yep, he's got a toolbar at the bottom of the view.

Comment: why you are trying to perform both button at a time.what is try to archive for that

Comment: I am bug testing the app. That is why. An app shouldn't crash just because you do something that you shouldn't / don't need.

Comment: @iDev There is no such thing as "navigation bar button". I am using bar button items which i place in the toolbar of the navigation controller. I can also place them in the navigation bar, the bug still occurs.

Comment: This is developer doubt clearing based not for testing. you would be post other stackoverflow childs sites

Comment: "developer doubt clearing". I am in doubt wether this is an actual bug or not. That's why I am asking here. I am sorry if it is that out of scope.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you call two segues at the same time and when you release the buttons the app tries to call one segue before the other segue has finished.

So what I can see is that the warning that Xcode presents is because one of your view controllers is triggered by the segue and the other segue for the other view controller is triggered without waiting for the loading end of the first view controller.

You can try to set bool or some sort of controller that checks when the first view controller has loaded and then trigger your other segue when you know that the first view controller has loaded properly.

Comment: Yes, I'm performing the segues manually now with my own boolean flag to check wether it is safe or not. Apple goes buggy segue code. Why do they encourage us to use story board segues when they are buggy?

Comment: Most of the problems and bugs I've encountered when I'm programming with Apples developer tool is with 99,9% of the time my own fault , so I can not really comment on Xcode bugs..

Comment: And this is exactly why I posted this here, to see if someone else could reproduce BEFORE posting a bug report on apple.

Comment: I just found this thread. Having the same problem. My sequence is Banner > Main (container embed) > detail (push) to notes (push). I also get "nested push animation can result in corrupted navigation bar" and also "Finishing up a navigation transition in an unexpected state. Navigation Bar subview tree might get corrupted" (it does). I can make this work by using a xib, but I would prefer not to. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same problem in my app by doing the following:
1 login (segue is performed with animation)
2 quickly make a selection on new screen (launches another segue)

if you try to perform a segue BEFORE the previous transition animation has completed, it can screw it up. So I added a delay before performing the segue and it seemed to fix it.
however, I don't think this is a final solution because the segue animation duration can differ depending on how fast the device is.

I think the best solution would be to trigger the segue AFTER viewDidAppear.

Answer (score 0):

I've just implemented something like that and it is now working.

So I have view controllers A, B & C. Normally users can navigate from A to B and from B to C but now I created a way that users can navigate from A to C (through B) automatically.

What I did was to create a public method in B saying to push C. This method looks like:

```
- (void)pushC {
    if ([self isViewLoaded] && self.navigationController.visibleViewController == self && ![self isBeingPresented] && self.didViewAppear) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CSegue" sender:self];
    }
    else {
        [self performSelector:@selector(pushC) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.4f];
    }
}
```

Everything is already given to you apart from that `didViewAppear` property. That one I set to true on `- viewDidAppear`.

Then I only need to call `- pushC` on the `- prepareForSegue` method in view controller A. As we've seen, he will wait for the right time to actually call the next segue.

This works alright but shows all the navigation transitions, which I don't need. I would prefer to be able to push a tree into the navigation controller so I would have only one transition navigation. Well, I guess I'll have to come back to this thing later.

This being said I don't think it's a bug but actually a change in behaviour in iOS7 because the animation got longer.